# using mod_rewrite to convert /?APP=XYZ&action=asdf&params=123 to /XYZ/asdf?params=123

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to setup a mod_rewrite that will allow for the following redirections:

1. my-domain/login => 
   my-domain/?action=login
2. my-domain/login?param1=xyz&param2=asdf => 
   my-domain/?action=login&param1=xyz&param2=asdf
3. my-domain/MYAPP/login => 
   my-domain/?APP=MYAPP&action=login
4. my-domain/MYAPP/login?param1=xyz&param2=asdf => 
   my-domain/?APP=MYAPP&action=login&params=xyz&param2=asdf

So far I have in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([A-Z]*)/([a-z]*)$ ?APP=$1&action=$2 [L]
```

This seems to work for scenarios 3 and 4 however it fails to pass the $_GET['action'] value to my script in scenarios 1 and 2.

EDIT: Changed .htaccess to:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]*)$ ?action=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Z]*)/([a-z]*)$ ?APP=$1&action=$2 [QSA]
```

This seems to work.

Comment: See the [`QSA` Flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa).

Comment: this has been asked many times -> http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A31039+rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question answered as above:

EDIT: Changed .htaccess to:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^([a-z]*)$ ?action=$1 [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^([A-Z]*)/([a-z]*)$ ?APP=$1&action=$2 [QSA]
```